# my AQuery not show image sometime

Tags: android

i m using aquery to load image form url and display and not use cache problem is some time screen show blank no image when i go back and again click on activity then screen show image why is show sometime imageview blank? what is meaning of false flast at this line androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false); ?????

```
  private AQuery androidAQuery;
 androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);
img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_button_image);



        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {



            JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
            String[] mVal = new String[school2.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {

                String name=         
                school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
                txt1.setText(name);

                String description=     
                school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("description");

                txt3.setText(description);

    String url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");


                            androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false);
```

Comment: what is siffrence between file cache memory cache?????

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
androidAQuery.id(img1).image(imageUrl, memeryCache, fileCache);
```

**MemeryCache :** if give url image in Android Query memmery cache then it will not again get from server so set true if you not want to get from server on each time

**FileCache :** if give url image in  Android Query file cache then it will not again get from server so set true if you not want to get from server on each time (In case memmery is not free or enough than it cache in file if we gave fileCache true)

Comment: i just want if server have image name myimage if i replace this image with another image which have same name myimage     then my imageview show new image not previous imaage how i will do this? which value set true which value set false?

Comment: i just want if server have image name myimage if i replace this image with another image which have same name myimage     then my imageview show new image not previous imaage how i will do this? which value set true which value set false?

Comment: im confuse both memorycache file cache look same meaning what is the diffrence

Comment: I Think first is find on memery cache and if not getting then find on file